# Editing info.plist file

Tags: macos

I'm trying to change an option in the **info.plist** file, but every time I try to change it, an error box says that the file cannot be unlocked.

To try and change the permissions of the file, I went to the file's info, but I couldn't see my name on there.

[image]

When I tried to add myself as a user, it didn't let me add a new user, saying:
**The operation cannot be completed because you don't have the necessary permission**.

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Is this plist loaded at the moment ? Try unloading it first.

Comment: How do I unload it? Is that the same as open? If so, it's not open. I don't know why it doesn't give me write privileges.

Comment: You can try **launchctl unload Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.OpenProgram.plist** but have you tried terminal to do the same thing ?

Comment: Yes, I have. It asked me to do it in recovery mode, so I will try that now. Is it safe to do in recovery mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Terminal & run the command below

   > sudo chmod u+w /FILE-PATH
2. Enter computer password when prompted.

***Note** : It doesn't show any characters while entering password*

3. Enter `ls -l FILE-NAME+FULL-PATH` in terminal to verify